# Failed processing format-parameters with mysql.connector in Python

Tags: python, mysql

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong with this insert statement. The error I'm getting is:

```
 "Failed processing format-parameters; %s" % err)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed processing format-parameters; 
'MySQLConverter' object has no attribute '_navigablestring_to_mysql'`
```

The specific lines of code are:

```
update = '''INSERT INTO myDB.newtable (ID,Record,Latitude,Longitude,code) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)'''
cursor2.execute(update,(ID,Record,Latitude,Longitude,code))
cnx2.commit()
```

I have also tried this format:

```
update = ("INSERT INTO myDB.newtable (ID,Record,Latitude,Longitude,code) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")%(ID,Record,Latitude,Longitude,code)
cursor2.execute(update)
```

and get this error:
`mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column '45676kb' in 'field list'`.

`45676kb` is only a portion of the entire value. The complete string is `45676kb-98734-98734-123nn`.

I think the syntax of the second attempt is more correct, because I'm at least getting an sql error but I can't figure out how to properly format my insert statement with mysql.connector.

Comment: The first way is the correct way. What are the `ID`,`Record`,`Latitude`,`Longitude` and `code` values?

Comment: `b8a0-4f8fe47a3e82, 4305-bd9d-5cf48c46c0c5, 38.922220, -77.205000, GS05`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first option is the correct way to put query parameters into the query - it is called a *parameterized query*. In this case, you are letting the database driver to escape the query parameters, safely insert them into the query and handle the Python-to-MySQL type conversions.

The error you are getting means that it could not convert one of the `ID`, `Record`, `Latitude`, `Longitude` or `code` parameter values to a valid MySQL database type. To be specific, see the variable types you have posted:

```
ID        <type 'unicode'> 
Record    <type 'unicode'>
Latitude  <class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>
Longitude <class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>
code      <type 'unicode'>
```

The problem is with `Latitude` and `Longitude` - they are `BeautifulSoup`'s [`NavigableString`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring) class instances - the MySQL converter having difficulties in understanding how to convert a `NavigableString` object into a valid MySQL type. Convert them to strings explicitly beforehand:

```
update = """
    INSERT INTO 
        myDB.newtable 
        (ID,Record,Latitude,Longitude,code) 
    VALUES 
        (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)
"""
cursor2.execute(update, (ID, Record, str(Latitude), str(Longitude), code))
```

Comment: these are the values for them: `b8a0-4f8fe47a3e82, 4305-bd9d-5cf48c46c0c5, 38.922220, -77.205000, GS05`

Comment: @user2338089 okay, let's review are you sure `b8a0-4f8fe47a3e82`, `4305-bd9d-5cf48c46c0c5` and `GS05` are strings? Could you also post the `type(variable)` for all of the 5 variables?

Comment: I get: `<type 'unicode'> <type 'unicode'> <class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'> <class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'> <type 'unicode'>` respectively

Comment: @user2338089 great, thanks, updated the answer. The mystery should be solved now.